# Javascript onClick event on React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So i'm relatively new to React.

I've seen quite a few questions about this but all the solutions have the onClick event attached and executed from within the React component.

I'm wondering, can I interact with my react component the same way I normally would? So my below is a `react component`

```
var tableMain = React.createClass({
render: function render() {

    console.log(tableModel, "summon the JSON data from tableModel!!");

    var thead = React.DOM.thead({},
        React.DOM.tr({},
            tableModel.map(function (col) {
                return React.DOM.th({}, col);
        })));

    var tbody = tableModel.rows.map(function (row) {
        return React.DOM.tr({},
        tableModel.cols.map(function (col) {
            return React.DOM.td({}, row[col] || "");
        }));
    });
    return React.DOM.table({}, [thead, tbody]);
}
});
```

Then in my js file, have an onlick event?

Comment: If you use event delegation, sure, why not? Question is, why would you want to? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I click on a td element, just for simplicity sake, I get a `alert("hello!");` i've looked in the react docs and they have the `onClick={function}` within the HTML that calls a function to handle it which is within the component. Just looks messy to me.

I am new though

Comment: That's not HTML. It's JSX. When the HTML gets appended to the DOM via Reactjs, it won't have `onclick="someFunctionCall()"` or anything. The idea is to create self contained components, so it makes sense for the click event to be contained within the component code in most cases.

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy Work with it for a bit and you'll *probably* find it nicer to work with and *much* easier to debug. React focuses a lot on co-locating things that front-end devs have traditionally seen as "separate concerns," but really maybe weren't. Check out [Rethinking Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7cQ3mrcKaY) for more info.